# How skydivers control their angular momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum

As the title says, how do skydivers stop spinning from an out of control spin while in freefall? Doesn't conservation of angular momentum doom them to keep spinning, even if they make a small mistake at the start of the freefall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A skydiver is *not* an isolated system, and therefore a skydiver's angular momentum is not conserved. Indeed, the drag forces on a skydiver are very great: terminal velocity for someone falling in a standard atmosphere is between $50{\rm m\,s^{-1}}$ to $60{\rm m\,s^{-1}}$. By shaping one's body, hands, or feet, one can control the moment of the system of these large drag forces on the body and I believe many skydiving suits have webbing to enhance the forces on controllable parts of the body. So not only can the skydiver choose the torques the drag imposes on him/her, they can also assume a bodyshape which has a "stable" moment of the force system: moments that tend to oppose any rotation.